# Zlib compression incompatibile C vs C# implementations

Tags: c#, zlib, compression, deflate

I'm trying to decompress data compressed with zlib algorithm in C# using 2 most legitimate libraries compatible with zlib algorithm and I got similar exception thrown.

Using DotNetZip:

```
Ionic.Zlib.ZlibException: Bad state (invalid stored block lengths)
```

Using Zlib.Net:

```
inflate: invalid stored block lenghts
```

but using same data as input to `zlib-flate` command on linux using only default parameters, works great and decompressed without any warnings (output is correct):

```
zlib-flate -uncompress < ./dbgZlib
```

Any suggestions what I can do in order to decompress this data in C# or why actually decompression failing in this case?

Compressed data as hex:

```
root@localhost:~# od -t x1 -An ./dbgZlib |tr -d '\n '
789c626063520b666060606262d26160d05307329999e70a6400e93c2066644080cf8c938c0c0c4d0d0d0d2d839c437c02dcfd0c0c0c11d28ea121013e7e41860ce18e210640e06810141669c080051840012eb970d790800090f99eee409ea189025e806c8e8b5354a89b13d81c136ca60f3a000e5fd6af0fb14a3221873e96400506374cd6c7d52dc8d98980657e7e06460ace0a4ce86e80da9f0249030edf816c16481ab06b60404f03931169c0cdc728c0db0fd928681a3042a481480347336c6e21320d78fb8155195a9090067ca3420387771a400a546aa70100000000ffff
```

Compressed data as base64:

```
root@localhost:~# base64 ./dbgZlib
eJxiYGNSC2ZgYGBiYtJhYNBTBzKZmecKZADpPCBmZECAz4yTjAwMTQ0NDS2DnEN8Atz9DAwMEdKO
oSEBPn5BhgzhjiEGQOBoEBQWacCABRhAAS65cNeQgACQ+Z7uQJ6hiQJegGyOi1NUqJsT2BwTbKYP
OgAOX9avD7FKMiGHPpZABQY3TNbH1S3I2YmAZX5+BkYKzgpM6G6A2p8CSQMO34FsFkgasGtgQE8D
kxFpwM3HKMDbD9koaBowQqSBSANHM2xuITINePuBVRlakJAGfKNCA4d3GkAKVGqnAQAAAAD//w==
```

Data after decompression, encoded with base64 look like this:

```
root@localhost:~# zlib-flate -uncompress < ./dbgZlib | base64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```

Comment: You're not showing how you're using the libraries so it's hard to answer the question. zlib-flate operates on a raw stream, the libraries can handle things like zip archives and the like.

Comment: @pvg: imho its irreverent, decompression code is  correct and compression code is unknown, but its from legitimate source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `zlib-flate` as a general-purpose compression algorithm which, according to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/zlib-flate.1.html) for it, you should not do:

> This program should not be used as a general purpose compression  tool.
>          Use something like gzip(1) instead.

So perhaps you should follow the instructions given by your tools and not use them for things that they are not intended for.  Use `gzip` and the `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream` instead, it's much simpler, especially when you're looking for cross-platform compatible compression algorithms.

That said...

The reason that you can't inflate the data is that it lacks a correct GZIP header.  If you add the right header to it you will get something that can be decompressed.

For instance:

```
public static byte[] DecompressZLibRaw(byte[] bCompressed)
{
    byte[] bHdr = new byte[] { 0x1F, 0x8b, 0x08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    using (var sOutput = new MemoryStream()) 
    using (var sCompressed = new MemoryStream())
    {
        sCompressed.Write(bHdr, 0, bHdr.Length);
        sCompressed.Write(bCompressed, 0, bCompressed.Length);
        sCompressed.Position = 0;
        using (var decomp = new GZipStream(sCompressed, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            decomp.CopyTo(sOutput);
        }
        return sOutput.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Adding the header makes all the difference.

---

NB: There are two bytes in the 10-byte GZIP header that are not stripped from your source.  These are normally used to store the compression flags and the source file system.  In the compressed data you present they are invalid values.  Additionally the file footer is abbreviated to 5 bytes instead of 8 bytes... all of which is not actually required for decompression.  Which probably has a lot to do with why the manpage says not to use this for general compression.

Comment: many thanks! this works great and actually in this case using data without header and part of footer is perfectly justified, bcs this part of compressed data is from streaming protocol where compressed data packets are mixed between uncompressed control data.

Comment: Um, no. You don't need to try to convert it to a gzip stream. It is a zlib stream, or at least starts as one. It already has a correct header. This is a standard way to transport compressed data that is more compact than gzip. There is no such thing as a "10-byte ZLib header". A zlib header is two bytes. You are providing a _gzip_ header, which is ten bytes. Also the "footer" that you think you see is not a footer. That is an empty stored block inserted when flushing the stream.

Comment: @MarkAdler Sorry, that should have been 'a 10-byte GZIP header'... I please lack of sleep :)  As for the footer... GZIP's simplest format places an 8-byte footer containing checksum and decompressed size at the end of the file.  Comparing the recompressed bytes to the sample, the last 5 bytes overlap the first 5 bytes of the GZIP footer.  Either can be deleted without preventing decompression.

Answer (score 3):

The stream you provided is not complete. It appears that you ended it with a `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` or `Z_FULL_FLUSH` in your C# code, instead of a `Z_FINISH` like you're supposed to. That is causing the error. If you terminate the stream properly, you won't have a problem.

zlib-flate is simply ignoring that error.

If you are not in control of the generation of the stream, you can still use zlib to decompress what's there. You just need to use it at a lower level where you operate on blocks of data and get the decompressed data available given the provided input.

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I can't control input stream compression, its part of legitimate protocol, also I'm not confident to do lower level changes in zlib library not from perspective that I couldn't do that, more from my approach to programming and code readability/maintainability. I assume you are in control of Zlib.net project, did it contain possibility of ignore that error like `zlib-flate` or `GZipStream` does? It looks like data can be successfully decompressed, I don't get why C# Zlib implementation requires that do decompression when it actually is not required at all.

Comment: I didn't say changes to the zlib library. I said use of the zlib library. You just need to use it properly.  You do not need to change the library.  You have not provided your decompression code, so we cannot help.