# Uncompress String with nodejs that was compressed using a C# snippet

Tags: c#, node.js, zlib, compression

I collect some large log infos using a C# tool. Therefore I searched for a way to compress that giant string and I found [this](https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/strings-komprimieren-und-dekomprimieren/1058) snippet to do the trick:

```cs
public static string CompressString(string text)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    var compressedData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
    memoryStream.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);

    var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer);
}
```

After my logging action the C# tool sends this compressed String to a node.js REST interface which writes it into a database.

Now (in my naive understanding of compression) I thought that I could simply use something like the follwoing code **on nodejs side** to uncompress it:

```js
zlib.gunzip(Buffer.from(compressedLogMessage, 'base64'), function(err, uncompressedLogMessage) {
  if(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log(uncompressedLogMessage.toString('utf-8'));
  }
});
```

But I get the error:

> { Error: incorrect header check
>       at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:370:17) errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }

It seems that the compression method does not match with the uncompression function. I expect that anyone with compression/uncompression knowledge could maybe see the issue(s) immediately.

What could I change or improve to make the uncompression work?

Thanks a lot!

========== UPDATE ===========

It seems that message receiving and base64 decoding works..
Using `CompressString("Hello World")` results in:

```
// before compression
"Hello World"
// after compression before base64 encoding
new byte[] { 11, 0, 0, 0, 31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 243, 72, 205, 201, 201, 87, 8, 207, 47, 202, 73, 1, 0, 86, 177, 23, 74, 11, 0, 0, 0 }
// after base64 encoding
CwAAAB+LCAAAAAAAAAPzSM3JyVcIzy/KSQEAVrEXSgsAAAA=
```

And on node js side:

```
// after var buf = Buffer.from('CwAAAB+LCAAAAAAAAAPzSM3JyVcIzy/KSQEAVrEXSgsAAAA=', 'base64');
{"buf":{"type":"Buffer","data":[11,0,0,0,31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,243,72,205,201,201,87,8,207,47,202,73,1,0,86,177,23,74,11,0,0,0]}}
// after zlib.gunzip(buf, function(err, dezipped) { ... }
```

> { Error: incorrect header check
>       at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:370:17) errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }

=============== Update 2 ==================

@01binary's answer was correct! That's the working solution:

```
function toArrayBuffer(buffer) {
  var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
    view[i] = buffer[i];
  }
  return arrayBuffer;
}

// Hello World (compressed with C#) => CwAAAB+LCAAAAAAAAAPzSM3JyVcIzy/KSQEAVrEXSgsAAAA= 

var arrayBuffer = toArrayBuffer(Buffer.from('CwAAAB+LCAAAAAAAAAPzSM3JyVcIzy/KSQEAVrEXSgsAAAA=', 'base64'))
var zlib = require('zlib');
zlib.gunzip(Buffer.from(arrayBuffer, 4), function(err, uncompressedMessage) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  else {
    console.log(uncompressedMessage.toString()) // Hello World
  }
});
```

Comment: Dont know about the nodejs side, but have you base64 decoded the string before unziping it? Eg can you break it down so that you first base64 decode and ensure the output is the same as what was on the C# side?

Comment: @AndrewHarris `Buffer.from(compressedLogMessage, 'base64')` should handle it for me but thanks for that hint. I will try it and update my question.

Comment: Additional info : u can also do this directly instead of reading memory and writing to byte . var compressedData = memoryStream.ToArray() .This will give byte array. Inbuilt method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet you found appears to write 4 extra bytes to the beginning of the output stream, containing the "uncompressed" size of the original data. The original author must have assumed that logic on the receiving end is going to read those 4 bytes, know that it needs to allocate a buffer of that size, and pass the rest of the stream (at +4 offset) to gunzip.

If you are using this signature on the Node side:
https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_arraybuffer_byteoffset_length

...then pass a byte offset of 4. The first two bytes of your gzip stream should be { 0x1F, 0x8b }, and you can see in your array that those two bytes start at offset 4. A simple example of the zlib header can be found here:

[Zlib compression incompatibile C vs C# implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387549/zlib-compression-incompatibile-c-vs-c-sharp-implementations?rq=1)

Comment: I will try it tomorror! And if it works accept your answer! Thanks a lot

Comment: It work's! Thank you so much! It seems that I have to wait 8 hours for appling the bounty.. But of course you are going to get it ;)